# Is there any easy way in Scala to Iterate over a Map[String, Set[String]] and if a Value for Key has more than 'n' number of Strings

Tags: scala

I am using Scala 2.12.3 and I have a `Map[String, Set[String]]` and I convert this Map to a Json String by using `mapper.writeValueAsString(map)`.
Later I call a web service for which I send this Json String as Request parameter. But the question is, I don't want any Pair my map should have more than 100 elements for each entry. For this example I am using 2 as limit.
If there are any, then my plan is to split these exceeding elements for the particular Key and prepare Map again, create the Json String again and call the webserver. I need to repeat this until I call the web service for all the entries in Map.

```
class ABC(productType: String, productValue: String)    

val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()   
val keySet = [ABC("abc", "123"), ABC("def", "456"), ABC("abc", "675"), ABC("abc", "982"), ABC("abc", "211"), ABC("def", "321"), ABC("xyz", "908")]
val requestMap = keysSet.foldLeft(Map[String, Set[String]] ()) { (k,v) =>
  val type = v.productType match {
    case "abc" => "abcList"
    case "def" => "defList"
    case "xyz" => "xyzList"
  }
  k+k.get(productType).map(x=> productValue-> (x+v.productType)).getOrElse(productValue-> Set(v.productType))
}

val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap)
```

I am expecting , the last line `val json = mapper.wrtieValueAsString` should be in a loop with each `requestMap` should have at the max 2 elements for each "abc", "def" and "xyz".

Comment: What is this? `type` keyword in identifier position, no `val`s in `ABC`, weird `[`-`]`-parens for something list-like, bunch of singleton types in all kind of places where it doesn't belong? Are you sure this compiles in 2.12? Also, definitions of `mapper` and `client` are not in the example, are they really relevant for the question?

Comment: type - I just used this as example, I should have named differently. Let me update.
mapper is not relevant, as I just mentioned here to show what I am doing with the map after I get it.
client is also not relevant , I just mentioned here to show what I am doing with the json string after I get it.

Comment: 1 - The more code you add that is "not relevant" the harder it is to find and focus on what _is_ relevant. 2 - Your code doesn't compile. After fixing 4 compiler errors I just gave up on trying to understand your question.

Comment: Updated the code by removing "not relevant".

Comment: It still doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

What you seem to want is to turn your `Map[String, Set[String]]` into `Map[String, List[Set[String]]]` first, so that each Set in the List is small enough. Or maybe you would rather go with `List[Map[String, Set[String]]]` instead.

But I don't see a way around the set-splitting step. You don't have to materialize the List in either case. I would not try to make it a one-liner for readability sake.